# Is it possible to repair a Mac external hard drive's partition table, without access to a Mac?

Tags: partition, data-recovery, hfs+, guid

I tried to create an NTFS partition on an HFS+ formatted Mac external hard drive, from within Windows. This hosed the GUID table.

In order to try to recover the files, I had to turn off journaling, and that required a Mac. One of the employees at my local Free Geek chapter lent me his Macbook during an Open Help Night last month, and I managed to disable journaling, but in the process, ended up wiping the whole partition table!

I currently don't have access to a Mac. I would have reformatted the external drive and started from scratch, but I literally don't have enough disk space in my house (only 250GB on my HDD, and there's more than 300GB stored on the external drive) to relocate the data while I wipe it. I ordered a 5TB external drive online, but it won't be here until Tuesday.

In the meantime, is it possible to rebuild the GUID partition table in Windows or Linux, or am I screwed?

The TestDisk log (executed on an Ubuntu live CD), if it helps:

```
Wed Jan 15 15:51:21 2020  
Command line: TestDisk 

TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015  
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Linux, kernel 5.0.0-13-generic (#14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019) x86_64
Compiler: GCC 8.2
ext2fs lib: 1.44.6, ntfs lib: libntfs-3g, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none, curses lib: ncurses 6.1
/dev/sda: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support  
/dev/sda: size       488397168 sectors  
/dev/sda: user_max   488397168 sectors  
/dev/sda: native_max 488397168 sectors  
/dev/sda: dco        488397168 sectors  
Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/mapper/control - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512
/dev/sr0 is not an ATA disk  
Hard disk list
Disk /dev/sda - 250 GB / 232 GiB - CHS 30401 255 63, sector size=512 - WDC WD2500JS-40TGB0, S/N:WD-WCANY1877189, FW:20.06C04  
Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 76000 255 63, sector size=4096 - Seagate Backup+  Desk, FW:0342
Disk /dev/sr0 - 4700 MB / 4482 MiB - 2295104 sectors, sector size=2048 - TSSTcorp DVD+/-RW SN-208BB, S/N:R8KK6GJC6001T1, FW:D300  

Partition table type (auto): Intel
Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - Seagate Backup+  Desk  
Partition table type: Mac  

Analyse Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 76000 255 63  
Current partition structure:
Bad MAC partition, invalid block0 signature
read_part_mac: bad DPME signature

search_part()
Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 76000 255 63  
NTFS at 0/32/33
filesystem size           1220940597
sectors_per_cluster       1
mft_lcn                   786432
mftmirr_lcn               2
clusters_per_mft_record   1
clusters_per_index_record 1
     Unknown                     2048 1220942644 1220940597 [Seagate Backup Plus Drive]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB
Partition not added.

HFSX magic value at 3/47/51

HFSX magic value at 3/47/51
part_size 1220858666
     HFS                        51206 1220909871 1220858666  
     HFSX blocksize=4096 + Backup, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB

Results
   P HFS                        51206 1220909871 1220858666  
     HFSX blocksize=4096 + Backup, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB

Hint for advanced users. dmsetup may be used if you prefer to avoid to rewrite the partition table for the moment:
echo "0 9766869328 linear /dev/sdb 409648" | dmsetup create test0  

interface_write()
   P HFS                        51206 1220909871 1220858666
Function write_part_mac not implemented
Partition table type (auto): Intel
Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - Seagate Backup+  Desk
Partition table type: EFI GPT

Analyse Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 76000 255 63
hdr_size=92
hdr_lba_self=1
hdr_lba_alt=1220942644 (expected 1220942644)
hdr_lba_start=6
hdr_lba_end=1220942639
hdr_lba_table=2
hdr_entries=128
hdr_entsz=128
hdr_size=92
hdr_lba_self=1220942644
hdr_lba_alt=1 (expected 1)
hdr_lba_start=6
hdr_lba_end=1220942639
hdr_lba_table=1220942640
hdr_entries=128
hdr_entsz=128
Trying alternate GPT
Current partition structure:
Trying alternate GPT

search_part()
Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 76000 255 63
NTFS at 0/32/33
filesystem size           1220940597
sectors_per_cluster       1
mft_lcn                   786432
mftmirr_lcn               2
clusters_per_mft_record   1
clusters_per_index_record 1

     MS Data                     2048 1220942644 1220940597 [Seagate Backup Plus Drive]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB

Results
   P MS Data                     2048 1220942644 1220940597 [Seagate Backup Plus Drive]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB

Hint for advanced users. dmsetup may be used if you prefer to avoid to rewrite the partition table for the moment:`  
echo "0 9767524776 linear /dev/sdb 16384" | dmsetup create test0`  

interface_write()
 P MS Data                     2048 1220942644 1220940597 [Seagate Backup Plus Drive]
simulate write!

TestDisk exited normally.
```

Comment: [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) is available for Linux or Windows.  If you run it with `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb` (Linux) or `gdisk64.exe 1:` (Windows) what does it show?  `GPT: damaged` or `GPT: not present`?   For more info have a look at the *gdisk* tutorial [Repairing GPT Disks](https://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html)

Comment: Did you try to **add** an NTFS partition (while shrinking the HFS+ partition) or did you try to reformat the HFS+ partition to NTFS?